# Silverlight RichTextBox Shader Effects

Tags: silverlight, richtextbox

Aside from rewriting the entire `RichTextBox` control, is there a way to apply the built-in shader effects (e.g. DropShadowEffect) to a specific piece of text or even a `Paragraph` or `Run`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the InlineUIContainer which can hold UIElements and apply Effects to those UIElements.  It's not pretty, but it works.

```
<RichTextBox>
<Paragraph>
    Displaying text with inline image
    <InlineUIContainer>
        <TextBlock Text="Hello World"><TextBlock.Effect><DropShadowEffect/></TextBlock.Effect></TextBlock>
    </InlineUIContainer>            
</Paragraph>
```